# How to append a dictionary in a Redis cache?

Tags: python, redis

I want to append a dictionary in a Redis cache.

I don't have any problem with **adding** a dictionary into the Redis but I cannot **append** several dictionaries into the Redis.

---

Here's an example:

```
import redis

cli = redis.Redis('localhost')

list_of_dict = [  # dummy
    {
        'tags': {'module': 'destructor', 'station': 'SNMP'},
        'metric_name': 'destructor',
        'value': -8555,
        'time': '2018-11-13T15:25:07'
    },
    {
        'tags': {'module': 'voltage', 'station': 'SNMP'},
        'metric_name': 'voltage',
        'value': 222,
        'time': '2018-11-13T15:25:09'
    }
]

from pprint import pprint

for ld in list_of_dict:
    cli.hmset("pythonDict", ld)
    # conn.append(key, val)  # Needs a key value.

pprint(cli.hgetall("pythonDict"))
```

---

In the above code snippet `.hmset()` writes only the **last** element/dict of `list_of_dict` into the Redis (override) and `.append()` needs the a `key,val`.

How can I write/append the **two dictionaries** of `list_of_dict` on Redis and retrieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions

1.use json

```py
import json
cli.set("pythonDict", json.dumps(list_of_dict))
print(json.loads(cli.get("pythonDict")))
```

2.use pickle

```py
import pickle
cli.set("pythonDict", pickle.dumps(list_of_dict))
print(pickle.loads(cli.get("pythonDict")))
```

if your dictionary key isn't string, you should use pickle.

Answer (score 3):

Set the key and value separately. Write the code in the following way:

```
for key,val in list_of_dict:
    cli.hset("pythonDict", key, val)

pprint(cli.hgetall("pythonDict"))
```

If you want to store the array as it is and retrieve the value use **`json`** package. Below is a sample:

```
import json
cli.set("pythonDict", json.dumps(list_of_dict))
pprint(json.loads(cli.get("pythonDict")))
```

Comment: I don't want to replace same named keys

Comment: Writing values to one key will always overwrite the value. Do you want the whole array to be saved?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to save an array

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using might turn suboptimal, as you are retrieving full data, appending to it, and saving it.
Since your requirement is iteratively appending to an existing list, **it is better you use a Redis** [LIST](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists).

The storage and retrieval approach would be:

1. Each element of your list would be a string ( which in turn is the
   JSON representation of your single dictionary element)
2. Whenever you want to append a dictionary to your existing cache, you
   use an [LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush) command on python's redis client. That would
   append your new dictionaries to existing Redis list.
3. For data retrieval, you would use [LRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/lrange) to retrieve your full
   or partial list of dictionaries. `LRANGE` has equivalent performance
   to `HGETALL`.

Example with redis client (the same set of commands can be used in the python redis client) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I encountered with this error: `ResponseError: wrong number of arguments for 'lpush' command.`

Comment: problem solved, I had a mistake in `.lpush()` argument, I forgaot the `name` arg.

Comment: What is `0`, `-1` meaning in `.lrange(name='pythonDict', start=0, end=-1)`?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari The 0 references the start of the list, and the -1 references the last element in this list. In essence, the 0 and -1 serve to get every element in this list. Hope this helped! (Over two years late, sorry about that!)